# PHP AJAX HTML: changing unique table data in foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, debugging

I'm new to PHP and Ajax. I am trying to create a table of object data where I can select the displayed data based on a `<select><option>...` form.

I have a PHTML template which looks like the following:

```
<?php
$content = "";
// creates data selector
$content .= "
            <form id = select_data>
                <select id = data_selection>
                    <option value = data1>Data 1</option>
                    <option value = data2>Data 2</option>
                    <option value = data3>Data 3</option>
                    <option value = data4>Data 4</option>
                </select>
            <input id = selected_data type=submit />
            </form>";
// creates table header
$content .= "
            <tr>
                <th>Data</th>
            </tr>";

$array_ids = array(1, 2, 3); // etc, array of object id's
foreach ($array_ids as $array_id) {
    $object = // instantiate object by array_id, pseudocode
    $object_data = $object->getData('default-data'); // get default data to display
    // create table item for each object
    $content .= "
                <tr>
                    <td><p>$object_data</p></td>
                </tr>";
}
print $content;
?>
```

This prints out the table content, loads objects by their id, then gets and displays default data within the `<p>` tag.
And then I have some Javascript which looks like the following:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_data').on('submit', function(e){ // get selected data type
        e.preventDefault();
        var data_selected = $("#data_selection :selected").val(); // create var to pass to ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'post.php',
            data: {data_selected: data_selected},
            success: function(data){
                $("p").html(data); // replace all <p> tag content with data
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This Javascript gets the selected data type, creates a variable out of it to pass on to the ajax which then calls `post.php`, which looks like the following:

````
<?php
$attribute = false;
if (isset($_POST['data_selected'])){
    $data = $_POST['data_selected']; // assigns variable out of ajax data
    $object = //instantiate object, again pseudocode
    $object_data = $object->getData($data); // get new data to replace into the ```<p>``` tag
    echo $object_data;
}
?>
````

The problem is that the Javascript that I have changes every single `<p>` tag to the last data iterated by the foreach loop because each `<p>` tag is not uniquely identified and the Ajax does not update the data based on a unique identifier, such as maybe the `$array_id`. Which brings me to my attempted solution.

I tried to identify each `<p>` tag with the following:

```
<td><p id = $array_id>$object_data</p></td>
```

And then creating a new Javascript variable out of the array ID:

```
var p_tag_id = <?php echo $array_id; ?>;
```

And finally making the Ajax success function target element ID's based on `var p_tag_id`:

```
$("#" + p_tag_id).html(data);
```

While this does not change all the `<p>` tags like previously, it only changes the final `<p>` tag and leaves all instances before it unchanged because the Javascript is not iterating over each `<p>` tag, or because the foreach loop does not call the Javascript as a function for each `$array_id`.

How can I rewrite this code so that the Ajax updates the data of each table item uniquely instead of updating them all with the same data? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Your HTML attributes are not properly quoted. `$('p')` would returns a jQuery Object that you would need to loop over like `$('p').each(function(){ $(this).html(data); });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I assigned the `$array_id` to each `<p>` tag after all in order to identify them uniquely:

```
<td><p id = $array_id>$object_data</p></td>
```

Then I looped over all the `<p>` tags and assigned the `$array_id` of `this` `<p>` tag to a variable like so:

```
$("p").each(function() {
    var array_id = $(this).attr("id");
```

And finally I made the Ajax `success` target elements based on their ID:

```
$("#" + array_id ).html(data);
```

Here is the full Javascript code for anybody who is interested. Hopefully this helps someone else out!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_data').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data_selected = $("#data_selection :selected").val();
        $("p").each(function() {
            var array_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'post.php',
                data: {data_selected: data_selected, array_id: array_id},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#" + array_id).html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Good sleuthing. Thanks for providing your solution for future puzzlers. +1

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to identify the table row containing the `<p>` tag you wish to update, and perhaps the `value` attribute of the SELECT element could help.

You can get the *number* of the clicked option from your `data_selected` variable by using slice to strip-off the last character (i.e. the number):

```
var num = data_selected.slice(-1) - 1;
```

*(Subtract 1 because the table rows are zero-indexed)*

Then, in the AJAX code block's success function:

```
$('table tr').each(function(i,v){
    if (i == num){
        $(v).find('td').find('p').html(data);
    }
});
```

The above grabs all the table rows (as a collection) and loops through them one-by-one. In the function, `i` is the index number of the row and `v` is the row itself. Index numbers begin at zero, which is why you earlier subtracted 1 from the (for eg) `data3` [3] value, leaving `num == 2`. When you find the right row number, use `.find()` to find the `<td>` in that row, and then the `<p>` in that `<td>` and Bob's yer uncle.

***I haven't tested the above code so there could be bugs in the example, but off-the-cuff this approach should work.***

Comment: This helped lead me to my solution. The code I provided was more an abstraction, but the `array_id` variables in the code I'm actually working with are unique 3-7 digit integers which are sufficient enough to identify each `<p>` tag. Identifying the table itself would get the same result, but I would need to change my code a bit more than I have.